# Using GmailApp.sendEmail, how to remove sent emails from sender's inbox

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

GmailApp.sendEmail remove sent emails from sender's inbox

I run a script to send emails using Google App Script GmailApp.sendEmail :

```
var emailErr = mailTab\[0\]\[i\] 
var subjectErr = "subject" 
var bodyErr = "texte" 
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailErr, subjectErr, bodyErr, { htmlBody: bodyErr, })
```

I run it every hour using a timer.

The problem is that even though I'm not myself in the list of recipients, I still receive it in my gmail inbox which is quite annoying. How to avoid it?

I tried to send it from an alias but it did not solve my problem.

The only way I found was to send it to a google group, and I think it automatically removed it from my inbox. But I also want to send it to other recipients

Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Google Workspace? (and not a public Gmail account)

If yes, you can add the `noReply: true` as following:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailErr, subjectErr, bodyErr, { htmlBody: bodyErr, noReply: true});
```

This way, your mail will be sent from noreply@domain, and won't be in your inbox.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app?hl=fr#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

If no, I'm afraid there is no solution :(